# How do I change Uncrustify configuration to indent variable names to the same column as the function name?

Tags: c, emacs, indentation, atom-editor, uncrustify

in my school we use a coding convention, which specifies to separate the name of the variable and its type (in C). In emacs, it would look like this :

```
static int        calc_dir(t_exe *exe, const int id)
{
  int             x0, y0;
  int             x1, y1;
}
```

Another convention is to use tabulations when possible, so here there are tabs between var/functions types and names. 
I actually want to switch from emacs to atom editor. I tried to play with a lot of options in uncrustify, to format my code, but I still can't find a way to do this : indent var names with the function name... All I got was to be able to specify an "absolute" number of columns between types and names, with the `align_var_def_gap` option, but its absolute, and does not fit if the function name (here "calc_dir")is, let's say 1 tabulation after...

```
static int       calc_dir(t_exe *exe, const int id)
{
  int    x0, y0;
  int    x1, y1;
}
```

It would be great if anyone had a config, or an idea !

Comment: (but versions look awful, btw. and are considered bad practice according to many reasonable style-guides)

Comment: I posted images because its a question about formatting, and it's easier to understand by looking at the two different editors/configs.

Comment: And I'm sorry, I can't change my school's coding convention... I was just asking for some help on the options of uncrustify.

Comment: How many spaces to put in a declaration between the type and the variable name is among the least interesting questions in C programming.  (How to automate this process is even less interesting.)  You should be devoting 5% or less of your energy to questions like this, and the other 95% to things that really matter.  If your school is making a big deal out of things like this, they need to readjust their priorities.  (Mind you, I'm not saying indentation and layout aren't important, but they're not *that* important.)

Comment: "school's coding convention" - every sane senior will complain on that style. So much for "school prepares for life". Anyway, you can very well show the formatting as text. No need for images.

Comment: // , On the other hand, learning how to deal flexibly with whatever weird style conventions a given project or organization has can come in handy in "life"